# how do I straighten Image using opencv and python?

Tags: python, opencv, zbar

I am using opencv and pyzbar to read a qr code in an image. The Pyzbar library also returns the shape of the image and the coordinate locations of the qr. I would like to align the qr vertically/straight if the image with the qr was not perfectly aligned. I have seen examples using Feature Based detection but that requires two images, the reference image and the image being used. I just want to align the cropped out image with qr code. This is my starting code. I have modified it to pick an image from url for ease of use.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyzbar.pyzbar as pyzbar
from skimage import io
url = "https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/19994bca1018ba79dd954bca9edc627dcd1f1dc0/d9ac1/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/19.jpg"
image = io.imread(url)
# image = cv2.imread("qr.jpeg")
decodedObjects = pyzbar.decode(image)
(x, y, w, h) = decodedObjects[0].rect
cropped = image[y-5:(y + h+5),x-5: (x + w+7)]
cv2.imshow("cropped", cropped)
cv2.imwrite("thumbnail.png", cropped)
```

Comment: See cv2.minAreaRect() to get the oriented rectangle corners. Then do a perspective warp to align with axis oriented rectangle. Search Google or this forum for minAreaRect.

Comment: Thank you, I will check on this. Sorry for the late reply